# The cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported

Tags: java, jdbc, cursor, prepared-statement, resultset

I met a ResultSet Error after using ResultSet, PreparedStatement, and with Microsoft JDBC Driver(version: 6.0). The Error Message is :

> Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported

My code is as below:

```
    public void usePreparedStatement_ResultSet_01() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(driver);

    try(
            Connection connectDB = DriverManager.getConnection(url+databaseName+user+password);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement("insert into person values(?,?,?)"
                                      , ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
                                      , ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {

        rs.next();
        rs.updateInt(1, 1005);
        rs.updateString(2,"boy"+3);
        rs.updateInt(3, 25);
        rs.updateRow();

    }
}

public static void main(String [] argv) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, SQLException,                                               ClassNotFoundException {

    useResultSet_01 insertDBbyResultSet = new useResultSet_01();
    insertDBbyResultSet.useConfig("D:\\Dropbox\\coding\\practices\\JAVA8-II_JDBC\\configTest1.txt");
    insertDBbyResultSet.usePreparedStatement_ResultSet_01();
    }
}
```

I have read the articles before posted this question. But I still don't uderstand two points:

1. Why can I not to use "executeUpdate" even I use the PreparedStatement?
2. How can I update my database if I want to use PreparedStatement with ResultSet like the written lines in my code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You use an updatable `ResultSet` with a `SELECT` query, not with an `INSERT`.

You're using everything wrong. Just use insert as you're using now (without any special parameters) and set the parameters with `setInt` etc. before calling `executeUpdate()`.

If you want to use an updatable `ResultSet`, put some data in the database, select them and then use the `rs.updateRow()` style.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up two different ways to insert data into the database:

1. [Inserting Rows in ResultSet Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_insert)

   This only works if the SQL-Query returns a ResultSet, for example when you execute a `SELECT`.

   ```
   try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {
       ResultSet uprs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");

       uprs.moveToInsertRow();

       uprs.updateInt(1, 1005);
       uprs.updateString(2,"boy"+3);
       uprs.updateInt(3, 25);

       uprs.insertRow();
       uprs.beforeFirst();
   } catch (SQLException e ) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   > ***Note:*** Not all JDBC drivers and databases support concurrency. The method DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetConcurrency returns true if the specified concurrency level is supported by the driver and false otherwise.
2. A simple Insert with `PreparedStatement`

   ```
   try(
           Connection connectDB = DriverManager.getConnection(url+databaseName+user+password);
           PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement("insert into person values(?,?,?)")
       ) {

       pstmt.setInt(1, 1005);
       pstmt.setString(2,"boy"+3);
       pstmt.setInt(3, 25);
       pstmt.executeUpdate();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The reference I used is from the book "細說JAVA 8" by a Chinese author "Li Gang". Here is his code:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class ResultSetTest
{
    private String driver;
    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    public void initParam(String paramFile)throws Exception
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(paramFile));
        driver = props.getProperty("driver");
        url = props.getProperty("url");
        user = props.getProperty("user");
        pass = props.getProperty("pass");
    }
    public void query(String sql)throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        try(
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url , user , pass);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql
                , ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
                , ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            **ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery())
        {
            rs.last();
            int rowCount = rs.getRow();
            for (int i = rowCount; i > 0 ; i-- )
            {
                rs.absolute(i);
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t"
                    + rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3));
                rs.updateString(2 , "studentName" + i);
                rs.updateRow();**
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ResultSetTest rt = new ResultSetTest();
        rt.initParam("mysql.ini");
        rt.query("select * from student_table");
    }
}
```

Maybe he is wrong.

Comment: This tutorial should be okay. But this "answer" is a part of the question, therefore please edit your question and append this.